# 日本語に違和感: 「票」

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

違和感まではないのですが、タイトルは他と揃えました。

Votesの訳は現在は`票`ですね。
好みの問題もあると思いますが、1文字だと見た目として短い様にも感じるので`得票数`を提案してみます。

Comment: 念のため確認: 質問一覧で、質問ごとに左端に表示されている「票」のことですよね。スクリーンショット: http://i.stack.imgur.com/erEcd.png

Answer (score 5):

オリジナルの質問と違う箇所かもしれませんが、質問の右下に表示されるタブの「票」という日本語も少しわかりにくいかもしれません。
[image: 画像キャプチャ]

「得票順」というのはどうでしょうか。その左に「古い順」と表示されているので、「○○順」という言葉で統一できると思います。